# Type error when passing server action to custom component

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I have a `<ClientForm>` form component using Radix Primitives,

```
"use client";
import { FC } from "react";
import * as Form from "@radix-ui/react-form";

const ClientForm: FC = (props) => (
  <Form.Root {...props}>
    <Form.Field name="name">
      <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="text" required />
    </Form.Field>
    <Form.Submit>OK</Form.Submit>
  </Form.Root>
);

export default ClientForm;
```

and I'm rendering this form component in `page.tsx` like the following. Among other attributes, I also want to pass in the server action to be called,

```
import ClientForm from "@/components/ClientForm";
// server action
import { create } from "@/app/actions";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <ClientForm action={create} />
    </section>
  );
};
```

Unfortunately this causes type error:

```
./src/app/page.tsx:8:19
Type error: Type '{ action: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'action' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

   6 |     <section>
   7 |       <h1>Home</h1>
>  8 |       <ClientForm action={create} />
     |                   ^
   9 |     </section>
  10 |   );
  11 | };
```

May I know how to allow the `ClientForm` component to accept the server action as well as other HTML form attributes?

Comment: What are you doing in `create`? I don't think you can hand a server action to a client component?

Comment: the `create()` is a server action which currently doing nothing but `console.log("Hello")`.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the type error,

```
const ClientForm = (props: React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"form">) => (
...
);
```